# Is it bad to hardcode settings in a class?

Tags: java, oop

I have an array of configs that while they may possibly change in the future, the likelihood is that they will never have to be changed.

If any are missing or incorrect then a certain feature of my system will not work correctly.

Should these still be retrieved be some sort of config, either xml, database etc and made available to the end user to change - or is this a good situation where it makes more sense to hard code them in the class that uses them?

I have spent a long time changing mind over and over on this.

Comment: If it ever turns out you need to modify these settings you would need to do a new release instead of editing these params in an xml and restart the system. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Like many things this is a balance. If you think that these properties won't change in the future and the effort of putting them in a properties (reading, injecting them) is more than trivial, put them in a class. One question to ask yourself is: when a constant becomes external configuration?

Comment: I normally use property files. And when a property definition is not found in a property file I use a hardcoded default value as a fallback.

Comment: Hardcoding is fine at the outset. When it is an actual business requirement/needed for testing then you upgrade it to a configurable parameter. If you believe it will be changed rarely then it is entirely non-agile to spend effort on infrastructure to make it configurable.

Comment: Any way you choose, it sounds like validation testing is a requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Designer's estimate of the likelihood of something needing to change is not a reliable criterion to make a decision, because real-world use of our programs has its peculiar ways of proving us wrong.

Instead of asking yourself "how likely is something to change?", ask yourself "does it make sense for an end-user to make a change?" If the answer is "yes", make it user-changeable; otherwise, make it changeable only through your code.

A particular mechanism through which you make something changeable (a database, a configuration file, a custom XML file, and so on) does not matter much. An important thing is to have good defaults for settings that are missing, so that your end-users would have harder time breaking your system by supplying partial configurations.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is to use any kind of config or properties file and use default values and failsafe if the file is damaged/missing. These approach has the following advantages:

- It can easily be recognised as a config file meaning another dev would not need to dive through your classes to change a parameter
- property files can be written by build tools like ant, so if you have e.g. a test server address and a productive server address the ant task could change the content accordingly
- it works with default values even without it

Disadvantage is the added complexity.

Comment: If one of the configs was a regular expression that was to be used in the function for pattern matching a value passed, would that sway you opinion?

Comment: I dont see a regex as a config, and no I would not put them into a external config file. I would propably encapsulate the different options and put mode1,mode2,etc. into the config. A config should not consist of detailed technical implementation data (you wouldn't put a image as bytearray into config, but you would put a link to it there if you catch my drift)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's almost certainly a bad idea to hard-code them; if nothing else, it can make testing (whether automated or manual) a lot more difficult than it needs to be. It's easy to include a `.properties` file in your jar with the usual defaults, and changing them in the future would just require overriding them at runtime. Dependency injection is usually an even better choice if you have the flexibility to arrange it.

Comment: +1, in particular for putting the defaults in a properties file (or some other kind of file) in the jar. That gets them out of the code and into a config file without incurring any extra deployment complexity. From there, it's a small step to taking an optional external configuration file instead, while being able to fall back to the shipped defaults. In an emergency, a sysop can even drop a new properties file into the jar by hand, which they can't easily do with class files.

Answer (score 0):

If the configs will never gonna change as you said then its fine if you declare those properties as a variable in interface or a separate class and use this constant through out the program.

Separate property files are used only when some property value are not fixed and is depend on environment like database name,username, password etc. Whereas some property are fixed and is not dependent on the environment in which it is going to deploy like portno, tablenames if any etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application. As a baseline, its good design to use static variables to hold data that your program will need, instead of hardcoding strings and integers all over the place; This means any changes (i.e. application wide font color) in the future will only require a single change, then a compile cycle and your good to go.

However, if these settings are user configurable, then they cannot be hard coded, but instead need to be read from an external source, and where you do it, is a matter of design, complexity and security.

Plain text files are good for a small application, where security is lax and things are plain text. The SublimeText editor and notepad++ editor do this for their theme settings and it works well. (I believe it was plain text, perhaps they have moved to XML now)

A better option is XML, as it is structured, easier to read/parse/write. Lots of projects use this as an option. One thing to look out for is corrupt files, while reading/writing to them, if the user closes the program or the JVM exits randomly for whatever reason. You might want to look at things like buffers. And also deal with FileNotFoundExceptions, if the text/xml file is missing.

Another option is a database file of some sort, its a bit more secure, you can add application level encryption and you have a multitude of options. Large programs that already use a DB backend, like MySQL, already have a database to hand, so create a new table and store the config there. Small applications can look at SQLite as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever hard code things if hey "might" change, or you might be sorry later and make others mad (very likely in big or/and open source projects). If the config will never change, it is not a config any more but a constant.

Only use hard coding when experimenting with code.

If you want to save simple values, you can user java properties.

Look [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) for an example.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are some properties you can change without having to retest the software.  These properties you have tested for a range of values, or you are sure it is safe to change with at most a restart.  This properties can be made configurable.

There are other properties which you cannot assume will just work without retesting the software.  In this case it is better to hard code them IMHO.  This encourages you to go through the release process when you change such a value.   Values which you never expect to change are a good candidate for this.